# hidden cells in LSTM doesn't work for autoregressive condition

Tags: python, time-series, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I use **LSTM with Scheduled Sampling** to do a fit a dynamic model. But what I found strange is that. When I evaluate a model with **autoregressive** task, If I **use the hidden cell from the last step**, the prediction is far from correct. While if I **init the hidden cell to zero at each step**, which means I don't use the memory from steps ahead, the prediction is much better. It really confused me. I'd be appreciated if anyone can help me with the code below.

Here is my code.

1. LSTM class

```
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, output_dim):
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        # (batch, seq, feature)
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hidden_dim, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)
        self.device = self.fc.weight.device

    def forward(self, x, hidden, teacher_forcing_ratio=0.5):
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = x.shape

        outputs = torch.zeros(batch_size, seq_len, self.hidden_dim).to(self.device)

        for t in range(seq_len):
            if t == 0 or np.random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio:  # use teacher forcing
                input_t = x[:, t, :]
            else:  # autoregressive
                tmp_out = self.fc2(outputs[:, t-1, :]).detach()
                # tmp_out = self.fc2(tmp_out).detach()
                input_t = torch.cat((x[:, t, :-1], tmp_out), dim=-1)
            input_t = input_t.unsqueeze(1)

            out, hidden = self.lstm(input_t, hidden)

            outputs[:, t, :] = out.squeeze(1)
        outputs = outputs[:, -1, :]
        outputs = self.fc2(outputs)
        return outputs, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        return (torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().to(self.device),
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim).requires_grad_().to(self.device))
```

2. train function

```py
def train(dataloader, model: LSTMModel, loss_fn, optimizer, scheduler=None, process_ratio=0.5):
    size = len(dataloader.dataset)
    train_loss = 0
    for batch, (X, y) in enumerate(dataloader):
        batch_size, seq_len, _ = X.shape
        # init hidden cells
        hidden = model.init_hidden(batch_size)

        # linear_value = 1 - process_ratio  # 1 --> 0
        pred, hidden = model(X, hidden, teacher_forcing_ratio=0.5)
        loss = loss_fn(pred, y)
        train_loss += loss.item()

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        # torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()
    scheduler.step()
    return train_loss
```

3. Autoregressive Evaluation

**`y` is the output value, `w_p` is a constant, I init the hidden at first and predict the value of the next 150 steps. And at each prediction, I get the hidden cell and pass it to the next step**

```py
y = [0]
wp = w
x = np.zeros((1, seqlen, 3))
x[:, :, 1] = wp
hidden = model.init_hidden(1)
for i in range(150):
    # x = scaler_x.transform(x.reshape(1, -1)).reshape(1, seqlen, -1)
    x = torch.FloatTensor(x).reshape(1, seqlen, -1)
    y_pred, hidden = model(x, hidden, teacher_forcing_ratio=1)
    # y_pred = scaler_y.inverse_transform(y_pred.detach().numpy())
    y0 = y_pred.item()
    y.append(y0)
    x = np.concatenate((
        x[0, 1:, :],
        np.array([1, wp, y0]).reshape(1, -1),
    ), axis=0)
```